# how to set a tableview delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uitableview

I'm trying to use a `UITableView` without using a nib and without using a `UITableViewController`.

I have added a `UITableView` instance to a `UIViewController` Like So

```
mytable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 207, 270, 233)];
[mytable setDelegate:self];
[self.view mytable];
```

Also I have added the following table view methods to my `UIViewController` (cut for brevities sake)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I am getting a warning saying that my `UIViewController` does not implement `UITableView` delegate protocol.

Whats the correct way to tell the table view where its delegate methods are?

(This is my first attempt at trying to use a `UITableView` without selecting the `UITableTableview` controller from the new file options)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to conform your class to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. ( `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol )

Do this by using angle brackets in your class interface definition:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {...}
```

The reason why you are getting this warning now and not before when you were using a `UITableViewController` is because `UITableViewController` already conforms to these protocols.

So, in essence a `UITableViewController` is just a class that conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, and has a `UITableView` instance member. 
That's pretty much it.

Of course, if you're not already subclassing `UITableViewController`, then you need to manually setup the `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `UITableView`:

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: o.k thanks guys, that made the error go away. I guess using <..> is when you want to implement more than one interface? I still have a problem, none of my tableview methods are getting called. [table reloadData] has no effect and also my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not executing when I click a cell. Can you think of anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to also set datasource aswell as the delegate

Answer (score 18):

You also must set the dataSource delegate to self:

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

or, equally:

```
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths The difference is purely stylistic. Both are setters and accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is just telling you that your `@interface` section should declare that you implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyUIViewController : UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableview setDataSource:self]
```

You have to give it definitely, Why because of the two **required** methods of `UITableView` are under `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3 this is how you set `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
class FeedsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
      @IBOutlet weak var feedsTableView: UITableView!
      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            feedsTableView.delegate = self
            feedsTableView.dataSource = self

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }
}
```