# Pass CLLocation data to UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5, cllocation

I'm trying to load my UITableView with distance from current location.  I'm taking small steps in just trying to get the Latitude to load into the UITableView.  My NSLog is reading the correct Lat/Long, but my Table is reading 0.000. At this point I'm not sure if it's my memory management or something else.  Please help.

My ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"

@interface TulsaMasterViewController : UITableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{   
    NSArray *_barInfo;
    CLLocationManager *lm; 
    NSString *currentLat; 
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *barInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentLat;

@end
```

My ViewController.m

```
#import "TulsaMasterViewController.h" 
#import "TulsaDetailViewController.h"  
#import "Bars.h"
#import "BarDatabase.h"

@implementation TulsaMasterViewController

@synthesize barInfo = _barInfo;
@synthesize currentLat = _currentLat;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{ 
    NSLog(@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);  
    NSLog(@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    currentLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{  
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Error obtaining location"]; 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];  
    [alert show];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
     return [self.barInfo count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//Get the object from the array.
Bars *barObj = [self.barInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Set the coffename.
cell.textLabel.text = barObj.barName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLat];


// Set up the cell
return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    TulsaDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.detailItem = [self.barInfo objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
   }
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.barInfo = [BarDatabase database].barInfo;
   lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   lm.delegate = self;
   [lm startUpdatingLocation];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your tableview when the didUpdateToLocation method is called

Comment: which I think would be [self.tableView reloadData] or something along those lines

Comment: Why would I update the TableView?  I only need my location once.  It seems like I'm missing something on getting my location into my TableView.  When I pull currentLat into the detailTextLabel.text its 0

Comment: Sunrize, I wasn't thinking before, but I do agree with you on updating the table.  However, the table still doesn't seem to be getting the locked in Latitude.  My NSLog is showing the correct lat/long, but the table never moves from 0.0000.

Comment: Whenever I do anything with the tableview, I make sure to conform the class to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols, which it looks like you haven't done. If you need help with that, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454567/how-to-set-a-tableview-delegate. Also, I would try declaring the tableview variable in your .h file, and make the IBOutlet connection from the variable to the tableview in your nib. Then, when you refer to the tableview, such as in the [tableview reload], it will refer to the tableview in your .nib file or the view you see in storyboard