# UITableViewCell in combination with UIButton and visualization issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to create a star button in my tableviewCells, so the user can save the favorite items.

I've tried this so far.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];        
    }

    UIButton *CameraBreak=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CameraBreak.frame=CGRectMake(260, 10, 60, 40);
    CameraBreak.tag=indexPath.row;
    [CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [CameraBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CameraBreak];  

    cell.textLabel.text = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];   

    return cell;
}
```

**The issue is that the buttons on viewDidLoad looks like this:**
[image: VIEWDIDLOAD]

**But once I scoll the table it buttons changes like this:**
[image: ON SCROLL]

Does anybody know the reason for this behavior? And how I can solve this?

**UPDATE**

Not selected:
[image]

Selected:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `accessoryView` property of `UITableViewCell` class.

```
// create your button here...    
[cell setAccessoryView:cameraBreak]; // or cell.accessoryView = cameraBreak;
```

Also, rename `CameraBreak` into `cameraBreak`. You should use **camelCaseNotation**.

Let me know if this works.

**Edit**

> Is this way also useful for the following idea: if (Accessory
>   selected) {show yellowstar.png } else (show graystar.png)

You can change the `imageView` property of `UITableViewCell`.

```
cell.imageView = // set the correct image
```

It's really simple to achieve this. Follow [how to set a tableview delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454567/how-to-set-a-tableview-delegate). In particular you should take a look at `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` protocol method.

Comment: Wow that worked out pretty well men! Thanks a lot!

Is this way also useful for the following idea:
if (Accessory selected) {show yellowstar.png
} else (show graystar.png)

Comment: @Foo If you want check the answer as replied (green check) and upvote too. This will help other people with the same problem. Cheers.

Comment: Is this way also useful for the following idea: if (Accessory selected) {show yellowstar.png } else (show graystar.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change UIButton type Custom in place of roundRect and you are adding buttons everytime you reload your table. So add all this code in braces where you are allocating your cell, so that they can be reused (not allocated repeatedly).

Replace this code

```
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
UIButton *CameraBreak=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];               
CameraBreak.frame=CGRectMake(260, 10, 60, 40);
CameraBreak.tag=indexPath.row;
[CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[CameraBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[cell.contentView addSubview:CameraBreak];
```

as

```
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
UIButton *CameraBreak=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];        

CameraBreak.frame=CGRectMake(260, 10, 60, 40);
CameraBreak.tag=indexPath.row;
[CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[CameraBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked::)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[cell.contentView addSubview:CameraBreak];

}
```

It will display properly.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but it just removed the RoundedRect. The issue remains the same.

Comment: It did help, but now the PNG is ONLY showing up once I select a cell. So once a cell is highlight I can see the .PNG

Comment: add this line also     [CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the result of many many buttons being added to each cell, one over the next.  All of that button creation code should happen inside the cell==nil condition.  That way it occurs on new cells only, not reused cells:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    UIButton *CameraBreak=[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CameraBreak.frame=CGRectMake(260, 10, 60, 40);
    CameraBreak.tag=indexPath.row;
    [CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [CameraBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(starClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CameraBreak];
}

// configure the parts of the cell here that vary based on indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I've changed my code as suggested, but now the png isn't showing up. The rounded rect is visible though. Any idea why?

Comment: UPDATE: now I've found out that the PNG is showing up once I select a cell. 

So once a cell is highlight I can see the .PNG

Comment: The button should be type UIButtonTypeCustom.

Comment: It is but please see my UPDATE above

Comment: The button code looks okay to me.  I noticed your starClicked selector had two colons, so that's probably a crash when you click the button (see my edit), but not sure about the image.  Can you post an image of the button in an unselected cell and in a selected one?