# Why is my table not loading data?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm doing something similar to the person's code in [how to set a tableview delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454567/how-to-set-a-tableview-delegate). However, one difference is I created a nib with a UITableView (along with other UIView elements), and I set the nib's File Owner to my custom class, which is defined as

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIViewConroller <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

In the nib, I set the Table View object's delegate and dataSource to the File Owner. When I load my view, I don't even hit the code for

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Do you do a `reloadData`? Is at least your MyCustomView shown, since there is a xib.

Comment: do you have implemented `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`?

Comment: Yes MyCustomView is shown. To do a reloadData, how do I get the UITableView object in my nib?

Answer (score 0):

lootsch gave me the clue. I do indeed do this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_myObjArray count];
}
```

But I was setting populating the array in the wrong place, so it was returning a count of 0. Hence I don't see the data!