# Tableview data won't load when unsegmented control is changed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

//The tableview is not changing.  I have been at this for days.  It seems so simple.  Thank you for your help

```
#import "StopsTableViewController.h"

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"RouteListing";

@interface StopsTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *TESTARRAY;

@end


@implementation StopsTableViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    
    if (self) {
        //Set the tab bar item's title
        self.title = @"Stops";
        
    }        
    
    self.stopList = [[API sharedAPI] fetchStopListing];
    
    self.TESTARRAY = @[@"Josh", @"Kyle", @"Nate"];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    
    // Adds Segmented Control
    [self segmentedView];    

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) segmentedView {
    NSArray *segmentedMenu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"Near Me", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentedMenu];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(valueChanged:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
    
}
```

## pragma mark - Table view data source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        return  [self.stopList count];
        
    }
    else {
        return [self.TESTARRAY count];
        
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        
            cell.textLabel.text = [[self.stopList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stoptitle"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stop %@", [[self.stopList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stopnumber"]];
    }
    
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.TESTARRAY[indexPath.row];
        
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

## pragma mark - Table view delegate

```
// In a xib-based application, navigation from a table can be handled in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
    // Create the next view controller.
    StopInfoViewController *detailViewController = [[StopInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StopInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    
    detailViewController.stopInfo = [[self.stopList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stopnumber"];
    
    detailViewController.stopName = [[self.stopList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stoptitle"];
    
    
    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}


//Function for segmentedView
-(void) valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
     
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"I'm getting called segment number is: %ld", (long)sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your datasource array before calling the table reload method and make sure that the array contains new values corresponding to the segment that you have selected.

Comment: I am kinda new to iOS development.  So what you're saying is I need to do something else in valueChanged? How can I change the datasource?

Comment: Your valueChanged function is calling correctly and inside that you are calling the tableview reload method. When you call reload, UITableView datasource get called again. So for changing the data loaded in the tableview, you need to change the data inside the array that you used to load the tableview.

Comment: Ok so let me make sure Im understand you correctly.  I need to have one array populate the tableview.  And inside of the valueChanged I need to change what array is setting the view.

Comment: That worked.   Thank you.  However now when I click that tab the table initially empty.  How do I get the data to load right away?  Thanks again

Comment: Yes you are correct. Also make sure that the delegates and datasource are set correctly.

Comment: Just call [self.tableView reloadData]; inside the viiewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the tableview delegates?

Try putting this in your `viewDidLoad` function.

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

If you want a fuller explanation, check here:

[how to set a tableview delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454567/how-to-set-a-tableview-delegate)

That post also explains how to ensure your class subscribes to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I have not I'm conforming to the delegates.  I have the at setup in my .h file <datasource/delegate>

Answer (score 0):

One thing I always run into when struggle up a table view is connecting the table with the interface using interface builder. Because it sounds like you're getting the data loaded, when the view first loads. But when you call `[self.tableView reloadData]` without having the connection made to the table, nothing will happen.

I ways forget that super simple step. Hope this helped